# Cross, Benes and Butterfly permutation. How make it?

Tags: pseudo-random-permutation

I'm not a math professional and researching an algorithm to provide a good permutation, I found references for Butterfly, Benes and Cross permutations.

But all papers I found are in fact discussing some enhancements and/or CPU mnemonics to these algorithms. I saw a lot of images like this, for BENES:

[image: BENES algorithm]

Since I'm not familiar with some aspects of that kind of image, I would like to understand somethings based on the following image:

[image: BENES algorithm]

1- I can understand the Control-Byte against the Data-Byte to provide a way to swap bits accordingly.

2- YELLOW bit can be ZERO or ONE (it depends of the corresponding Control-Bit). If zeroed, it affects the RED circle; but if ONE, it goes straight to the PURPLE.

3- But CYAN bit *also* may affect *the same* bits!

It's weird and confuse!

Let's suppose my CONTROL-BYTE is 0x00001111 or even 11110000. In these cases, I will see YELLOW or CYAN affecting the same result bit (PURPLE or RED).

I tried to research some "basic" math to understand it but I really got no sucess at all!

I would like to make a C# routine (I'm not worried about performance) to provide same schema on BITS, BYTES and even INTEGERS...

Thank you in advance for the patience in explain this to me.

**UPDATE**

Some links where I found the information above:

[Fast Subword Permutation Instructions Using Omega and Flip Network Stages](https://www.princeton.edu/~rblee/PUpapers/iccd00_omflip.pdf)

[Efficient Permutation Insctructions for Fast Software Cryptography](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/d48d/17391a65f35965d4098d77f94a14c68e5113.pdf)

[Bit Permutations](http://programming.sirrida.de/bit_perm.html#butterfly)

[Pipeline and SIMD Parallel Processing Principles](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=ygpD8USsiBIC&pg=PA165&lpg=PA165&dq=how%20butterfly%20permutation%20functions&source=bl&ots=xxRPhCiv_P&sig=sEkTa6MRtGNF0gm3-4VABMvZbno&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi6hPWPvpjUAhVBlZAKHZ8LAkA4ChDoAQgnMAA#v=onepage&q=how%20butterfly%20permutation%20functions&f=false)